# Блокировка кнопки Home

Tags: android

Заканчиваю писать свой экран блокировки. Все методы вызова экрана, блокировка стандартного локера и прочее уже реализованы. Остается одна лишь проблема - блокировка кнопки Home. Перепробовал кучу идей, поэтому вариант с установкой приложения как главного экрана, библиотека shaobin0604 для дизактивации клавиш не подходят. Первый - просто по способу работы, второй - по причине невнятной работе на всех моих 3 устройствах. Минимальная версия SDK - 14. Уже неделю бьюсь, подскажите лучший способ решить проблему..

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с 14 версии SDK Home Button перекрыть нельзя. Сделал это Google из целей безопасности.

Comment: Было бы неплохо еще и ссылку на источник дополнительно привести, т.к. сказать можно многое ) Ссылки не приветствуются, если ответ можно узнать только по ссылке, но если вы что-то пишите и приводите дополнительно ссылку - ничего плохого не будет. Особенно здесь - может там где-нибудь написано, что "нельзя, но если хочется, то можно сделать вот так", а вы просто этого не заметили. А так ссылку привели - кто не верит словам, может сам ознакомиться